# How to get element index

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need get `element.dataset.index`, i try create function

```
function fullDescriptionMob2(){
    $(".tabs__controls__item").on('click', function () {
         $test =  $(this).dataset.index;
        console.log($test);
    })
}
```

but it's dosn't work.

P.S. on page 5 element with class `".tabs__controls__item"` i need get index element, by which be click.

Comment: Please share the relevant HTML and explain the issue around it

Comment: `$test = this.dataset.index;` or `$test = $(this).data('index');` depending on whether you want to dom or jquery api .

Comment: what is dataset.index exactly? `this` (from what I know) is bound to html element in jQuery, so I doubt it will contain anything like that

Comment: @ishidex2 correction, dataset does exist, I never used it though. The problem is that $(this) returns jQuery element not DOM element

Answer (score 0):

Answer @Yoshi work, thanks!

Need be used:

```
 $test = $(this).data('index');
```